# Regarding CAG India what does this line "CAG satisfies himself about the wisdom, faithfulness and economy of the expenditure incurred." means

Tags: india, terminology

I came across this line about the duties of CAG in a book.

*He satisfies himself about the wisdom, faithfulness and economy of the expenditure incurred.*

What does this line mean? What does satisfy mean here, in what way.

Background:

[CAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comptroller_and_Auditor_General_of_India) is Comptroller and Auditor General of India. His office is very powerful one and stands as the guardian of Indian Government. He looks after all the expenses made by Government of Union of India and States of India.

Answer (score 1):

The CAG is an Auditing body, which is called in to probe some financial irregularities. These lines probably mean that, he probes a matter until he satisfies himself that expenses occurred were legal (faithful) and reasonable (economy).